# AngularJS; Model data not being listed in an html table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```html
<table class = "table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>URL</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
      <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code is how my html side looks like. I see the table on the page but without the data from the controller. Following is my controller code. What can I do to fix this?

```js
angular.module('clientBookApp')
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.movies = [
      {
        title: 'Captain America',
        url: 'https://www.captainamerica.com'
      }
    ];
  });
```

I tried adding ng-controller in a body tag but it didn't work.

```html
<body ng-app="clientBookApp" ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have `ng-controller` in the html?

Comment: I tried adding it to a body tag but didn't work.

Comment: Can you post what have you tired? It seems the problem will be `ng-controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just because `this` its different from `$scope`

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.movies = [{
    title: 'Captain America',
    url: 'https://www.captainamerica.com'
  }];
  this.movies = [{
    title: 'Iron Man',
    url: 'https://www.ironman.com'
  }];
  console.log(this === $scope);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

if you wanna use `this` you don't need to inject `$scope`, but you need to use the `controller as` syntax as follow.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", [
  function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.movies = [{
      title: 'Iron Man',
      url: 'https://www.ironman.com'
    }];
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="movie in vm.movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amighty/kef1setn/)

Everything looks good on your code. Only issue is your angular app module missing `[]` and you should use `$scope` in place of `this`.

```
<body ng-app="clientBookApp" ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

angular.module('clientBookApp',[])
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.movies = [
      {
        title: 'Captain America',
        url: 'https://www.captainamerica.com'
      }
    ];
  });
```